# AlpineJS x-for showing an extra iteration

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

Having a strange issue, when using x-for to loop through an array i am getting an additional blank set of form elements.  If i take out all of the code between the templates and just replace with a h1 with x-text as event.name - i only get the 2 iterations.

Puling my hair out, any ideas why this might be occuring?  Here is the code.

Appreciate your assistance.

I have confirmed that the array being passed in only has 2 entries.

```
            <div x-data="updateEvent()">
                <template x-for="event in events">


                    <form action="test10" @submit.prevent="submitData">


                        <div class="grid grid-cols-4 gap 4 flex">

                            <div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="flex items-center content-center justify-center py-5">




                                <img class="w-full rounded" :src="imagePath + event.image" alt="" />
                            </div>




                            <div>
                                <div class="pl-4 my-10">
                                    <div>
                                        <x-label for="name" :value="__('Name')" class="mb-2" />

                                        <x-input id="name" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="name"
                                            ::value="" x-model="event.name" x-bind:disabled="!disabled" required
                                            autofocus />

                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <x-label for="date" :value="__('Date')" />

                                        <x-input id="date" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text" name="date"
                                            ::value="" x-model="event.date" required autofocus />

                                    </div>


                                    <div>
                                        <x-label for="statsLink" :value="__('Stats Link')" />

                                        <x-input id="statsLink" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text"
                                            name="statsLink" ::value="" x-model="event.statsLink" required
                                            autofocus />

                                    </div>

                                    <div>
                                        <x-label for="frontLink" :value="__('Front Link')" />

                                        <x-input id="frontLink" class="block mt-1 w-full" type="text"
                                            name="frontLink" ::value="" x-model="event.frontLink" required
                                            autofocus />

                                    </div>

                                </div>


                            </div>

                            <div class="flex items-center content-center justify-center ">
                                <x-button class="ml-3" x-on:click="disabled = !disabled, save = !save">
                                    Edit Event
                                </x-button>
                                <br />
                                <x-button class="ml-3" x-bind:disabled="!disabled">
                                    Update Event
                                </x-button>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </form>


                </template>

            </div>
```

I have tried cutting down the code to H1 and then it seems to iterate correctly - only twice.

Adding in the updateEvent() code for reference.

```
`<script>
    function updateEvent() {
        return {
            events: [{
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Event Name 1',
                    date: '2023-02-11 00:00:00',
                    image: '/eventCoverImages/EventCoverImage1.jpg',
                    cards: null
                },
                {
                    id: 2,
                    name: 'Event Name 2',
                    date: '2023-01-14 00:00:00',
                    image: '/eventCoverImages/EventCoverImage2.jpg',
                    cards: null

                }
            ],
            show: true,
            disabled: false,
            save: true,
            imagePath: "{{ asset('app') . '/' }}",


        }


    }
```

`

Comment: Try to provide a unique [:key attribute](https://alpinejs.dev/directives/for#keys).

Comment: I tried :key="event.id" - This didnt seem to achieve any different result.

Comment: Then could you please add an example of `updateEvent()` that reproduces the issue? The template code looks fine.

Comment: You're using the translate function without quotes. High chance JS will pick this up as a constant/variable, instead of a string. These are found on the `x-label`, try `:value="'__('Name')'"` (Note the wrapping single quotes)

Comment: Thanks for your responses!

@Dauros - Updating the main question with the updateEvent()

Changing the translate as you say comes back with a syntax error - "unexpected identifier "Name", expecting "]""

Comment: Guys i think this could have something to do with something else I copied a tutorial which essentially does the same thing and am getting a similar issue, the x-for iterating too many times (https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-iterate-through-data-with-the-x-for-attribute-in-alpine-js @ 57 seconds) 

I think my syntax is right - any ideas how I would troubleshoot this?

Comment: I think i resolved it.  It seemed that alpine was being pulled in in two places, one in my layout  and one in my app.js - I removed from my layout and it seemed to resolve some issues.  

There then seemed to be another issue where my input was coming in blank, it seems the ::value="" was overwriting the x-model.  removed and all fixed.

I appreciate your help, very frustrating and nice to have the support.